# How to find Equation of motions and Hamilton Function for this Lagrangian?

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics

$$L = \frac{m \dot{x}^2}{2} - \exp(|x|) $$

I would appreciate if you could explain the steps needed to get the answer

Comment: yes that is the method I am trying to use, from what I understand, I need two Lagrange equations

for x 
I need to find dl/dx-d/dt*dl/dx

Comment: are they correct equations ?

Comment: The number of Euler-Lagrange equations is directly related to the degrees of freedom you have. Do you know how many do you have? This is the first step towards the solution.

Comment: thank you for your reply
In this question I would say I have one degree of freedom

Comment: Good. How many equations will you have then?

Comment: one equation only

Comment: I should first find 
dl/dx 

I am unsure how to differentiate x with a dot above it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the discussion was getting too long in the comments. Since we've established the system has one degree of freedom we find that there is only one Euler-Lagrange equation to solve:

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}}.$$

Remember that $\dot{x}$ means the time derivative of $x$, i.e.

$$\dot{x} := \frac{dx}{dt}.$$

Nevertheless, what matters is that you partially differentiate the Lagrangian and equate the parts. Are you sure that the potential is $\exp(|x|)$, the exponential of the modulus of $x$? This would lead to

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} = \text{sign}(x) \exp(|x|) = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{x}} \frac{m \dot{x}^2}{2} = m \ddot{x}.$$

Quite hard to integrate.

Comment: thanks for your reply, really appreciate it

so what your saying is I need to partially differentiate L with respet to t and $\dot{x}$ ? , then multiply the two together. 

yes I am sure of the second part is indeed e^ modulus(x)

Comment: No. You partially differentiate $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to $\dot{x}$. You take the result and then you differentiate with respect to time. In this case the only function that is a function of the time is $\dot{x}$, leading to the above result. You're not multiplying anything.

Comment: oh right so $$ \ddot{x}.$$ is final answer.

if $$\dot{x} := \frac{dx}{dt}.$$

how can you differentiate something with respect to a dx/dt

Comment: That is a whole different story (to which I don't know the answer yet). But you should do it. Haha.

Comment: oh right ? so your not sure what the final answer is

Comment: The final answer is as stated: $m\ddot{x} = \text{sign}(x) \exp(|x|)$. This is the equation of motion. What I was referring to is how you can differentiate a function with respect to another function.